# Erro ao adicionar condição ternária dentro de um ui-sref

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou fazendo um link em uma página que irá redirecionar de acordo com os dados do objeto. Então fiz um condição ternária, porém está dando um erro de syntaxe e não consigo ver o que está errado:

Meu html:

```html
<a class="article-home-small" ui-sref="obj.content_type == 'article' ? article({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)}) : article_blog({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)})">
```

O erro:

`Syntax Error: Token ')' is an unexpected token at column 39 of the expression [{uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)}) : article_blog({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)}] starting at [) : article_blog({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)}].`

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso dentro de `ui-sref` você precisa de dois pares de chaves `{{}}`:

```
<a class="article-home-small" ui-sref="{{obj.content_type == 'article' ? article({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)}) : article_blog({uid: obj.uid, title: slug(obj.title)})}}">
```

Comment: Deu este erro: `Error: Invalid state ref ''` sem mesmo eu clicar em nada.

Comment: Tenta usar uma função no lugar o `ui-sref` e coloca no `ng-click`. A função recebe `obj` como parâmetro e depois faz a logica que você precisa antes de enviar para a pagina certa.